# Powershell script to extract data from multiple text files into an excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm pretty new to PS and been struggling for a few days.
I have multiple text files in a folder with specific data that I would like to extract into an excel spreadsheet.
each files look like this :

```
Client n° : xxx Client name : xxx

                Computer status

pc group 1 : 

n°1 OK                   n°2 Disconnected               n°3 Unresponsive
n°4 Unreachable host     n°5 Unresponsive

Data read 11/11/20 12:50:07

Version: x.x.x
```

I would like to have an output file that looks like this :

```
 Client name and n°     OK       Disconnected      Unresponsive    Unreachable host   version       
     xxx/xxx            1             1                2                 1             x.x.x
```

For the status columns it's the sum number of pc with that status and not the pc n° that I would like to display.

At the moment I'm working with multiple .bat files that searches for the status and output one file per status

```
find /c "Disconnected" *.* > disconnected.txt
find /c "Unresponsive" *.* > unresponsive.txt
```

And then I sort every single output in an excel which takes me too much time, I was wondering if it was possible to automate this task with a script.

I really don't have any knowledge of PS, only basic batch commands.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you have already tried. Explain what didn't work and if you received error messages, add them to the question aswell. Withour showing your own effort, this is just asking for someone to write the code for you..

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your files are all in one folder and all of them have the `.txt` extension.

Then you need to loop through these files and parse the data you need from it:

```
# create a Hashtable to add the different status values in
$status = @{'OK' = 0; 'Disconnected'= 0; 'Unresponsive' = 0; 'Unreachable host'= 0}

# loop through the files in your path and parse the information out
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object {
    switch -Regex -File $_.FullName {
        '^Client n°\s*:\s*([^\s]+)\s+Client name\s*:\s*(.+)$' {
            # start collecting data for this client
            $client = '{0}/{1}' -f $matches[2], $matches[1]
            # reset the Hashtable to keep track of the status values
            $status = @{'OK' = 0; 'Disconnected'= 0; 'Unresponsive' = 0; 'Unreachable host'= 0 }
        }
        '^\d+' {
            # increment the various statuses in the Hahstable
            ($_ -split '\d+').Trim() | ForEach-Object { $status[$_]++ }
        }
        '^Version:\s(.+)$' {
            $version = $matches[1]
            # since this is the last line for this client, output the collected data as object
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                'Client name and n°' = $client
                'OK'                 = $status['OK']
                'Disconnected'       = $status['Disconnected']
                'Unresponsive'       = $status['Unresponsive']
                'Unreachable host'   = $status['Unreachable host']
                'Version'            = $version
            }
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\clientdata.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Result on screen:

```
Client name and n° OK Disconnected Unresponsive Unreachable host Version
------------------ -- ------------ ------------ ---------------- -------
xxx/xxx             1            1            2                1 x.x.x
```

Comment: It's working wonderfully, just some thing here and there that I need to adapt. This value "'n°\d+'" I'm assuming it refers to the pc number, I made a mistake on the example file the status is actually as follow : 1 OK           2 Unresponsive     so the "n°" is actually not there in the original file

Answer (score 0):

I used this as an exercise to test my abilities. I created three of the same files, with different data, and tested this script. 
As long as they are text files in the directory the script will iterate through each file and pull the data from each as you stated it needs to be. If a stray text file gets added the script does not know nor care and will treat it like the others. If there is data it can find it will, and it will output that data to the excel file. Lastly the file is set to save itself and then immediately close.

It starts by Creating the Excel file, then Workbook. (I commented out the naming of the workbook. If you like you can add it back.) Finds all text files in a directory, then searches the text for the specific content within the text you specified above.

During the script I commented as much as I thought might be needed to assist with modification later on.

Output formatted like this:
[Excel Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bjok.png)

```
#Create An Excel File
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $True

#Add Workbook
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

<#Rename Workbook
$workbook= $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$workbook.Name = 'Client name and #'#>

#create the column headers
$workbook.Cells.Item(1,1) = 'Client name and n°'
$workbook.Cells.Item(1,2) = 'OK'
$workbook.Cells.Item(1,3) = 'Disconnected'
$workbook.Cells.Item(1,4) = 'Unresponsive'
$workbook.Cells.Item(1,5) = 'Unreachable'
$workbook.Cells.Item(1,6) = 'Version'
$workbook.Cells.Item(1,7) = 'Date Gathered'

$move = "C:\Users\iNet\Desktop\Testing"
$root = "C:\Users\iNet\Desktop\Testing"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Filter *.txt

#Starting on Row 2
[int]$i = 2
ForEach ($file in $files){
   
$location = $root+"\"+$file

#Format your client data to output what you want to see. 
$ClientData = select-string -path "$location" -pattern "Client"
$ClientData = $ClientData.line
$ClientData = $ClientData -replace "Client n° :" -replace ""
$ClientData = $ClientData -replace "Client name :" -replace "|"
$row = $i
$Column = 1
$workbook.Cells.Item($row,$column)= "$ClientData"

#Data Read Date
$DataReadDate = select-string -path "$location" -pattern "Data read"
$DataReadDate = $DataReadDate.line
$DataReadDate = $DataReadDate -replace "Data read " -replace ""
    #Data Read Date, you asked for everything but this.
$row = $i
$Column = 7
$workbook.Cells.Item($row,$column)= "$DataReadDate" 

#Version
$Version = select-string -path "$location" -pattern "Version:"
$Version = $Version.line
$Version = $Version -replace "Version: " -replace ""
$row = $i
$Column = 6
$workbook.Cells.Item($row,$column)= "$Version"

#How Many Times Unresponsive Shows Up
$Unresponsive = (Get-Content "$location" | select-string -pattern "Unresponsive").length
$row = $i
$Column = 4
$workbook.Cells.Item($row,$column)= "$Unresponsive"
 
#How Many Times Disconnected Shows Up
$Disconnected = (Get-Content "$location" | select-string -pattern "Disconnected").length
$row = $i
$Column = 3
$workbook.Cells.Item($row,$column)= "$Disconnected"

#How Many Times Unreachable host Shows Up
$Unreachable = (Get-Content "$location" | select-string -pattern "Unreachable host").length
$row = $i
$Column = 5
$workbook.Cells.Item($row,$column)= "$Unreachable"

#How Many Times OK Shows Up
$OK = (Get-Content "$location" | select-string -pattern "OK").length
$row = $i
$Column = 2
$workbook.Cells.Item($row,$column)= "$OK"
#Iterate by one so each text file goes to its own line.
$i++
}

#Save Document
$output = "\Output.xlsx"
$FinalOutput = $move+$output
#saving & closing the file
$workbook.SaveAs($move)
$excel.Quit()
```